# how to launch AR apps on emulator?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-emulator, arcore

I'm developing an AR app using unity but I don't have an android mobile so I decided to work on an emulator and I read all documentation about it but it didn't work. the app is installed but when I open it I see a black screen with a cube for testing if it works right, the virtual scene doesn't open do you have any solutions?. I tried all the solutions but none of them work for me.
note: I installed an AR app from google play but it crashed.

- specifications:
- mobile: pixel 3a
- Android version:11 (30 API).
- Android Studio version:(4.1.1).
- Ar foundation:4.1.9.
- ARCore XR Pkugin:4.1.9.
- google play services for ar: installed.
- player settings:
  [image: player settings]
- plug-in providers
  [image: plug-in providers]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think unity supports emulator based testing i tried to do the testing on xcode using emulators but the entire option didn't open up one of my seniors suggested to me that there will be a difference since some use ARM architecture and mobile emulators might not use them, so emulator checking is out of the question, easiest way to check though since unity can adapt to cross platform and iphone 6s is cheapest and the last device to support ARKit you can take that alternative by building it with Xcode.

There are logical reasons too because when you launch an AR App the mobile camera comes into play but emulator has a hard time trying to connect camera even if you do manage it you will still be disappointed with the experience